# Is there any way to check the relocation progress of shards in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Yesterday, I was adding a node to production elasticsearch cluster once I added it I can use **/_cat/health** api to check number of relocating shards. And there is another api **/_cat/shards** to check which shards are getting relocated. However, is there any way or api to check live progress of shards/data movement to the newly added node. Suppose there is a 13GB shards, we've added a node to es cluster can we check how much percent, GBs(MBs or KBs) has moved currently so that we can have a estimate of how much time it will take for reallocation.

Can this be implemented by on our own or suggest this to elasticsearch? If it can be implemented on our own, how to proceed or what pre-requisites I need to know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have

```
GET _cat/recovery?active_only=true&v
GET _cat/recovery?active_only=true&h=index,shard,source_node,target_node,bytes_percent,time
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-recovery.html

Comment: Does time parameter actually tell us how much time relocating shards/indexes will take?

Comment: this is the actual execution time. for unfinished tasks, how long it is already running.

Comment: For those who looking for detailed one along with total bytes and bytes transferred at that point in time:
_cat/recovery?active_only=true&h=index,shard,source_node,target_node,bytes_percent,bytes,bytes_total,bytes_recovered,time&v

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the Pending Tasks API :

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tasks.html

*The task management API returns information about tasks currently executing on one or more nodes in the cluster.*

`GET /_tasks`

You can also see the reasons for the allocation using the allocation explain API:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-allocation-explain.html

`GET _cluster/allocation/explain`

Comment: Above endpoints will provide the status what is currently going on es cluster. It will not provide the exact amount of data or size (in GiBs, MiBs, etc) has been moved from 1 node to another in percentage or value. @IIermaly let me know if you are not clear with my statements. I'll reframe it.

Comment: Is there any to check relocation progress status or we need to build something on our own?